# Let $f$ be continuous on a compact set $X$ and let $f(x)>0\,\,\,\, \forall x \in X$ show that there is a $\alpha>0$...

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be continuous on a compact set $X$ and let $f(x)>0\,\,\,\, \forall x \in X$ show that there is a $\alpha>0$ so that  $f(x)\ge \alpha \,\,\,\,\forall x \in X$.

Let $f:X \longrightarrow Y:x \mapsto f(x)\,\,$, be any continuous function with $X$ being the compact domain, than $f(X)$ is also compact.

Since $f(x)>0\,\,\,\, \forall x \in X \,\, \Longrightarrow \min(f(X))>0$

By definition $\,\,\min(f(X)) \leq f(x) \,\,\,\, \forall x \in X$

So set $\alpha:=\min(f(X)) \,\, \Longrightarrow 0<\alpha \leq f(x) \,\,\,\, \forall x \in X $

could someone check my reasoning and tell me if this works, or whats wrong?
That would be great :)

Comment: I don't see any errors.. Looks good to me.

Comment: Maybe you could add a short argument explaining why $\min(f(X))$ exists.

Comment: Yeah i thought this follows from $f(X)$ is also compact

Comment: @CoffeeArabica But you should mention it nevertheless.

Comment: okey , thanks :) (btw : is it okey to post his exercises and ask weither it makes sense? (i study maths by myself atm so nothing about getting more points on any assigndment)

Comment: The key points you need to mention are that $f(X)$ is compact and therefore the minimum exists. The proof is correct.

Comment: @CoffeeArabica If you're looking for someone to check your work you can use the solution-verification tag in your post.